# Spring Security Custom Auth Manager approach

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I would like to access the http request, specifically auth header in AuthenticationManager.authenticate() context.

Requirement is to authenticate a custom token. There is an external library which does that and so I don't have the luxury to read out principal from the token. Hence, in the custom filter, I am returning the full token in the getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal() method. This seems borderline incorrect and I would like to not pass the token pretending it to be principal.

Is there any way I can get it without violating any framework constraints?
Or is there a better way to handle the scenario which I'm trying to achieve?

Here's the config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{

        CustomTokenFilter customTokenFilter = new CustomTokenFilter();
        customTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(new CustomAuthenticationMgr());

        httpSecurity
                 // csrf etc etc
                .addFilter(customTokenFilter)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/users/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/other-api/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

Here's the custom token filter class:

```
public class CustomTokenFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authorization = request.getHeader("authorization");

        if(authorization.indexOf("Custom") == 0){
            return Map.of("Custom",authorization.split(" ")[1]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And finally, the custom authentication manager class:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationMgr implements AuthenticationManager {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        Map<String,String> map = (Map) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String token = map.get("Custom");

        // Custom validation - checking length here just to simplify
        if(token.length() > 0)
            authentication.setAuthenticated(true);

        return authentication;
    }
}
```

**Version**: Spring Boot 2.6.7 (transitive: spring-core 5.3.19)

**Constraints**: Cannot upgrade to other versions at the moment

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this isn't a good way to do it. (It's great you noticed -- too few people care whether their code is idiomatic.)

A better way would be to start by writing your own filter that actually just... does the authentication. You can extend `OncePerRequestFilter` rather than something more specific. That's what Spring Security itself does, both for basic authentication ([BasicAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html)) and for OAuth bearer tokens ([BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.html)). You may want to take a careful look at the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/625a1cdca2a34b6de1154ceda52e0e1d893993da/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java) for `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` since the problem it solves is very similar to yours. (I wouldn't extend it, though, since it's very clearly intended to do OAuth specifically. I wouldn't straight up copy the code either -- it's fairly simple as Spring Security filters go but probably still does more than you need. Try to understand the code instead; that will help a lot with your understanding of Spring Security in general.)

Okay, so you have a filter which looks a lot like `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`. That is, it contains an `AuthenticationManager` and its `doFilter` method consists of extracting the token from the request, passing that into the `AuthenticationManager` and then doing some `SecurityContext`-related stuff. Except, problem: `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` expects an `Authentication`, not a String, and the token is a String.

The solution is to write a wrapper object for your token which implements `Authentication`. You can do this a couple of ways. Personally, what I'd do is use two classes: one which you pass into `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()`, and one which you get back. So we have, say, `CustomTokenAuthenticationRequest implements Authentication` and `CustomTokenAuthentication implements Authentication`. Both are immutable.

`CustomTokenAuthenticationRequest` basically just contains the token; its `isAuthenticated()` is `return false`, its `getPrincipal()` returns the token and its `getCredentials()` also returns the token. This is essentially what Spring Security itself does with [BearerTokenAuthenticationToken](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/625a1cdca2a34b6de1154ceda52e0e1d893993da/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationToken.java).

`CustomTokenAuthentication`, on the other hand, probably contains a `UserDetails` of some sort; its `isAuthenticated()` is `return true`, its `getName()` is a username or user id or something, etc.

Now you need to teach the `AuthenticationManager` to authenticate `CustomTokenAuthenticationRequest`s. The way to do this isn't to implement `AuthenticationManager`, it's to implement `AuthenticationProvider`. So you write a class that looks roughly like

```java
public class CustomTokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication a) {
    String token = ((CustomTokenAuthenticationRequest) a).getToken();
    if (/* the token is valid */) {
      CustomTokenAuthentication returnValue = // whatever you want it to be
      return returnValue;
    }
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authClass) {
    return authClass == CustomTokenAuthenticationRequest.class;
  }
}
```

Finally, wire it all up. Add the authentication provider to your `HttpSecurity` using its `authenticationProvider()` method. (If you do this, and you don't change the default authentication manager configuration, `authenticationProvider()` results in your authentication provider getting added to an `AuthenticationManager` which Spring Security configures *for you* -- an instance of `ProviderManager`.) Add the filter using `addFilterAt(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)`. Also, don't call `httpBasic()` because this adds a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` which I am guessing you don't want. Or maybe you want basic authentication *and also* your custom token authentication? But you didn't say that. If you do want both, you'll want to add your filter with `addFilterBefore` or `addFilterAfter`, and you need to think about ordering. Generally filter ordering is important in Spring Security.

I glossed over a *lot* of stuff here, barely gave you any code, and still wrote something of blog post length. Spring Security is very complex, and the thing you're trying to do isn't easily done in an idiomatic manner if you don't have much experience. I highly recommend just reading the Spring Security reference documentation from start to finish before you try implementing any of my suggestions. You'll also need to read quite a lot of Javadoc and tutorials and/or framework code. If there's something specific you want to follow up on I might respond to a comment, but I don't promise it; I had to do some research for this answer and have already spent more time on it than I planned to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting the approach and I get it now how it'll work. I missed to look at the BearerToken auth filter and that's where I'm going next!  

I have some experience with Spring Security but it has always been straight forward using JWT so far. 
For this ask, I've spent quite some time going through spring security courses to actually understand the concepts in detail and dig deeper into the framework. I've read the documentation in parts but never fully gone through all of it. May be now's the time.
Appreciate your time and the details in your answer.

Comment: And doesn't look like I need the http basic filter so will remove it.

Answer (score -2):

you should look spring-security-lambda-dsl,add filter,add auth provider

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the auth provider part of the solution you're suggesting?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).